# Is there a word for a feeling of impending doom or dread?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a feeling of impending doom or dread?

For example, what word could be used in the following sentence?

> I walked into the bar and felt ______. I knew something terrible was about to happen, but I couldn't place my finger on what, or why.

Comment: "I have a bad feeling about this." http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/I_have_a_bad_feeling_about_this

Comment: [Oh Crap!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OhCrap)

Comment: an uncanny feeling.

Answer (score 24):

My preferred word for this is *foreboding*. Here is the entry for foreboding from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreboding):

> : a feeling that something bad is going to happen.

Some examples from the entry:

> She was filled with a sense of foreboding.
>
> It seems that her forebodings were justified.

Answer (score 9):

You could say that you have an [ominous](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20ominous) feeling:

> giving the impression that something bad or unpleasant is going to happen;
>
> threatening; inauspicious.
>
> synonyms: threatening, menacing, baleful, forbidding, sinister, inauspicious, unpropitious, unfavorable, unpromising; portentous, foreboding, fateful, premonitory; black, dark, gloomy; formalminatory; literarydireful; rareminacious
>
> "ominous clouds"

Answer (score 8):

You could try *premonition* (which isn't solely restricted to negative future scenarios, but has that connotation by default):

Definition (via Oxford Dictionaries Online):

> A strong feeling that something is about to happen, especially
>   something unpleasant

Example:

> He had a premonition of imminent disaster.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider, [***presentiment***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22presentiment+of+imminent%22&biw=442&bih=290&prmd=nsiv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtnP3Eo5vMAhXClxoKHa8UCSIQ_AUICygG)

> A feeling or impression that something is about to happen, especially something evil; foreboding.
>
> Origin of presentiment: 1705--15; < French, now obsolete spelling of pressentiment. See pre-, sentiment
>
> presentimental, adjective
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presentiment)

Answer (score 1):

uneasy, suspicious, anxiety, apprehensiveness, trepidation...

**EXAMPLES:**
The man felt **uneasy**.
She was **suspicious** of what was to come.
The child was **anxious** about the future.
An **apprehensive** look fell over his face.
The room was filled with **trepidation**.